# Modify filter to apply only to the visible rows in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to filter the content in table using `dropdown filter`. Below is my code.  It works perfectly alright when this only filter applied. But when it's applied over any other filter, it also takes hidden rows into account. That's how it is incompatible with multiple filters. I am not very much experienced in Jquery. So I will appreciate if any one could give input for the same.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   function addRemoveClass(theRows) {

        theRows.removeClass("odd even");
        theRows.filter("tr:visible:odd").addClass("odd");
        theRows.filter("tr:visible:even").addClass("even");
    }
    var rows = $("table#testTable tr:not(:first-child)");

 //   addRemoveClass(rows);


    $("#selectField1").on("change", function() {

        var selected = this.value;

        if (selected != "All") {

            rows.filter("[OHQ=" + selected + "]").show();
            rows.not("[OHQ=" + selected + "]").hide();
           addRemoveClass(visibleRows);
        } else {

            rows.show();
           addRemoveClass(rows);

        }

    });
});
```

Comment: can you please state your problem a bit more specifically?

Comment: Can you also paste your HTML code? This way it would be easier to create a JS Fiddle and try to solve your problem.

Comment: @ZombieChowder below is my code and table generated dynamically from db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to cumulate filters, is to re-apply all filters at each change, so also picking up the value(s) of any other input that defines the combined filter. This can you do by creating one event handler for all filter-input changes, and processing the values of all inputs in that handler to build one combined filter.

Secondly, to color the rows in alternating fashion, even when filtered, you should get the rows by filtering for `:visible`, and then use the jQuery specific `:odd` and `:even` selectors.

See the snippet below for a demo:

```js
var $rows = $("table#testTable tr:not(:first-child)");

function addRemoveClass() {
    var $visibleRows = $rows.filter(':visible');
    $visibleRows.removeClass("odd even");
    $visibleRows.filter(':odd').addClass("odd");
    $visibleRows.filter(':even').addClass("even");
}

$("#selectField, #selectField1").on("change", function() {
    var $filteredRows = $rows;
    // filter by the first input:
    var selected = $('#selectField').val();
    if (selected != "All") {
        $filteredRows = $filteredRows.filter("[position=" + selected + "]");
    }
    // accumulate the second input into the filter:
    selected = $('#selectField1').val();
    if (selected != "All") {
        $filteredRows = $filteredRows.filter("[OHQ=" + selected + "]");
    }
    // hide all rows, and then make the filtered rows visible:
    $rows.hide();
    $filteredRows.show();
    // apply the styles for alternating odd/even rows:
    addRemoveClass();
});

addRemoveClass();
```

```css
.even { background: #ccc; }
.odd { background: #eee; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
position:
  <select id="selectField">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>&nbsp;
OHQ:
  <select id="selectField1">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
  </select>
</p>
<table id="testTable">
  <tr><th>header</th></tr>
  <tr position="1" OHQ="a"><td>row 1, position=1, OHQ=a</td></tr>
  <tr position="2" OHQ="a"><td>row 2, position=2, OHQ=a</td></tr>
  <tr position="2" OHQ="a"><td>row 3, position=2, OHQ=a</td></tr>
  <tr position="2" OHQ="b"><td>row 4, position=2, OHQ=b</td></tr>
  <tr position="3" OHQ="b"><td>row 5, position=3, OHQ=b</td></tr>
  <tr position="3" OHQ="c"><td>row 6, position=3, OHQ=c</td></tr>
</table>
```

Note that the `:odd` and `:even` selectors use the zero-based numbering, so the first (visible) row will be regarded as *even*. Swap the class names if you want it the other way round.

Comment: Hello Sir, Thanks for your quick response. But it is working same way as before. It applies filter for entire table instead of only visible rows.

Comment: I updated my answer to deal with the question on accumulating filters.